# match the last position in a word - regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string of several-letter sequences (8 - 14 letters) like this:

```
    HYHIVQKF, YGEIFEKF, DQGNRTTPSYV, CCHPLLLPQPRGE, PPKTHMTHHPISD, FIAVGYVDDTQFVR, DTQFVRFDSDAASQ, SLPSGFAQW, ...
```

How can I use regular expressions to find the sequences that matches the last letter of each sequence? For example, how can I find the sequences whose last letter is an F?

Comment: Can you show the example output?

Answer (score 1):

`\w+F\b` should be what you are searching for.
It matches every word (sequence of `a-z`, `A-Z`, or `0-9`) that ends with an F.
For a more restrictive match, use `[A-Z]+F\b`.
If you also want to match a single F, use `[A-Z]*F\b`.

You can see the results [here](https://regex101.com/r/KaczmF/1).